# Rearranging series and "placid" permutations

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

*This question came out of a conversation with my students about [Riemann's rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem), and the general problem of which permutations are "safe" w/r/t summing infinite series.*

Let $S_\infty$ be the group of permutations of $\mathbb{N}$. For a sequence $\mathscr{A}=(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$, say that a permutation $p\in S_\infty$ is **$\mathscr{A}$-placid** iff for every $q\in S_\infty$ and every pair of integers $z_0, z_1$ we have $$\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}a_{q(i)}\simeq \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}a_{p^{z_0}\circ q\circ p^{z_1}(i)}$$ where "$s\simeq t$" means "either $s$ and $t$ are each undefined, or they are defined and equal." Basically, $p$ is $\mathscr{A}$-placid if $p$ is never interesting from the point of view of rearranging the terms in $\mathscr{A}$. For example, the permutation swapping $2i$ and $2i+1$ for each $i$ is $\mathscr{A}$-placid for every $\mathscr{A}$.

I'm curious whether placidity actually depends on the sequence in question *(restricting attention to sequences whose corresponding series converge conditionally, to avoid triviality)*. For example, are the following equivalent?

- $p$ is placid with respect to the alternating harmonic sequence $((-1)^{i+1}{1\over i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$.
- $p$ is $\mathscr{A}$-placid for every conditionally convergent sequence $\mathscr{A}$.

I suspect the answer is negative, but I don't immediately see how to prove it.

---

EDIT: as far as I can tell, the only "obviously placid" permutations are those in which there is a finite bound on the distance an element of $\mathbb{N}$ is moved. Merely having finite orbits isn't enough: for example, for any conditionally convergent sequence $\mathscr{S}$ there is a permutation of $\mathbb{N}$ of order $2$ which applied to $\mathscr{S}$ results in a series with limit $+\infty$. This was pointed out to me by a colleague after I brashly claimed otherwise!

EDIT THE SECOND: Now [asked at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424390/rearrangement-conditional-convergence-and-placid-permutations).

Comment: Interesting question. Do you have any example with unbounded orbits?

Comment: $1/(4n+2)+1/(8n^2+4n)=1/(4n+4)+1/(4n^2+4n)$, so a permutation that swaps $4n+2$ with $4n+4$, and $8n^2+4n$ with $4n^2+4n$ for lots of $n$ should be placid for the alternating harmonic series; but since that second swap is unbounded, there should be a series for which it isn't placid.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Note the "$\forall q$" part of the definition of placidity - it's not obvious to me that the permutation you describe is actually placid for the harmonic series.

Comment: @lulu Not yet! It's entirely plausible to me that, as long as $\mathscr{A}$ converges conditionally, the only $\mathscr{A}$-placid permutations are those with no unbounded orbits.

Comment: Sorry, Noah, I didn't read the definition carefully enough.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Incidentally, it's not clear to me that that's the "right" definition yet. But I'm basically looking for a way to associate, to a sequence $\mathscr{A}$, a group of symmetries that are boring from the point of view of rearranging $\mathscr{A}$. If we just look at $\mathscr{A}$ itself, it's no longer true (I think) that the product of two "$\mathscr{A}$-preserving" permutations need still be "$\mathscr{A}$-preserving" in general.